# I am not able to add existing project(.net core worker service app) as azure webjob in .net core 3.1 web application

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, backgroundworker, azure-webjobs, azure-eventhub

I have created a worker service to consume my eventhub data and save that into cosmos db. But I want to deploy my worker service with my web app which is an .net core web application.

Can anyone help me out here to get my job done ?
What architecture I should follow for it?
[image]

Comment: What is your question? I think you have a wrong understanding of webjob?

Comment: Hi @JasonPan I have understanding of webjobs but I want to deploy my job with my webapi. Previously we had option in .net core to add other project as webjobs inside other application for the deployment purpose. Have a look at image please.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Upgrade Visual Studio Enterprise 2019（`Version 16.7.7`） to the latest version, the problem still exists.

After my test (using `Visual Studio Enterprise 2019` `16.0.30406.217 D16.7`), I found that when you add `Existing Project as Azure Webjob` to the webapp of the `.net framework`, it can be successful.

But I cannot add it to the webapp of `.net core`. **I think this is a bug**.

Suggestions can [raise a support ticket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to confirm and seek official help.

Comment: I checked azure docs again and found out that It is clearly mentioned that .net core webjobs can't linked with web project. But This options still appears in VS for core project which is quite confusing.